# Woocommerce: Show only "to" price for a group product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have some grouped products on our woocommerce powered webshop, we use them for workshops so the grouped product has some linked products which are payment choices, deposit, remaining payment and full payment.

So a 5000 dollar workshop will have linked products: a 500 dollar deposit, a 4500 remaining payment and a 5000 full payment

Problem is, woocommerce displays the from and to price as $500-$5000 - and I would like to **only** show the "To" price, in this case $5000

Anyone have a code snippet that makes this possible?

Thanks so much

Flemming

Comment: I think you will have to write your own function to override whichever function in wc-template-functions.php is outputting this. Can you trace back to find which one it is?

Comment: I have seen people do some custom output for pricing by editing price.php (one of the woocommerce files, used for outputting prices on a single product) - I do not quite have the php or woocommerce knowledge though to code it myself, was hoping some woocommerce/php wiz could point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "woocommerce_grouped_price_html" filter.

```
function max_grouped_price( $price_this_get_price_suffix, $instance, $child_prices ) { 

    return wc_price(max($child_prices)); 
}; 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_grouped_price_html', 'max_grouped_price', 10, 3 );
```

Just add this snippet to functions.php